# Cannot return object from generic method

Tags: java, generics, extends

I don't understand why following code does not compile. I've declared generic type `T` which extends `Customer`. `Customer` is of type `Customer` so why I cannot return `Customer` object from this method without a cast?

```
public class CustomerExample {

    public <T extends Customer> T processCustomer(Customer customer) {
        return new Customer();
    }
}

class Customer {

}
```

I get `java: incompatible types: Customer cannot be converted to T`

Comment: The error message is loud and clear `java: incompatible types: Customer cannot be converted to T`

Comment: You need to cast it, won't work without casting.

Comment: what about return (T) new Customer();

Comment: what about changing the method signature to `public <T extends Customer> Customer processCustomer(T customer)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` extends `Customer` but `Customer` doesn't extend `T`.

In your actual code :

```
public <T extends Customer> T processCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return new Customer();
}
```

You return a super class instance (`Customer`) in a method that declares as returned type the subclass of it (`T`).
It is not valid to do it without downcast as it is not valid to assign a super class variable to a subclass variable such as :

```
T t = customer;
```

You should write :

```
T t = (T)customer;
```

Consequently you also need to cast to `T` here :

```
public <T extends Customer> T processCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return (T) new Customer();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to explicitly cast:

```
public <T extends Customer> T processCustomer(Customer customer) {
    return (T) new Customer();
}
```

Of course, **you need to be aware of this type cast for the runtime**, because you cannot do this:

```
class Client extends Customer {
}
```

With this, the following call will fail at runtime with a class cast exception:

```
Client client = new CustomerExample().processCustomer(new Client());
```

That's because the runtime classes won't match. This simply means that your implementation of `processCustomer` must be effectively generic (not be bound to one static type anyway)

Comment: this solution is not best solution - when you create:

public class YetAnotherCustomer extends Customer {
}

and 

public class YetAnotherCustomerExample extends CustomerExample {
}

and after:

        YetAnotherCustomerExample ce = new YetAnotherCustomerExample();
        YetAnotherCustomer result = ce.processCustomer(null);
you will receive:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Customer cannot be cast to YetAnotherCustomer
 at App.main(App.java:5)

Comment: @THM I suspect you didn't read my answer carefully... I explicitly warned about the runtime exception for instances involving other subclasses of `Customer` (you wouldn't even have to extend `CustomerExample` to produce the class cast exception)... But the first/main part was to answer the original question (why it wasn't compiling)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you called your method with:

```
Customer customer = ...
SomeCustomerSubClass c = processCustomer(customer);
```

In that case the compiler expects `processCustomer` to return a `SomeCustomerSubClass`, so it cannot allow your `processCustomer` to return a `Customer`.

If you are returning a `Customer` instance, you should be asking yourself why use a generic type parameter in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that as the author of the method, you don't get to decide what the method's generic parameters are. You cannot assert that `T` *must be* `Customer`. The caller can.

In your case, you constrained `T` to be a subclass of `Customer` or `Customer` itself. Yet you return an instance of `Customer`. This creates a contradiction if the caller specifies `T` to be `AngryCustomer` (a subclass of `Customer`). The caller expects you to return an `AngryCustomer` but you returned a `Customer`!

To fix this, you can change `extends` to `super` so that `T` can be any superclass of `Customer` or `Customer` itself. Now it all makes sense. If the caller specifies `T` to be `Object`, the `Customer` type is compatible with `Object`, but not compatible with `AngryCustomer`.

Alternatively, don't use generics at all. Your current implementation of this method does not seem suitable to be generic.

Comment: "To fix this, you can change extends to super so that T can be any superclass of Customer or Customer itself. " You cannot replace `extends` by `super` such as :   `public <T super Customer> T ...` The generic type declaration can be only `T` or `T extends`. What you describes looks like to lowerbounded wildcards used for method parameters with generic types. Which is another thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, **Customer** do not implement **T**

e.g. lets create T like:

```
class T extends Customer {
    int i;
    public T(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

how you want to create **T** using **Customer** ? it is impossible.